# installing OpenCV 2.0 on Ubuntu Karmic: still get ImportError from "import cv" in Python

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, python, opencv

I have tried compiling and installing from the 2.0.0 release source, the SVN head, and from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gijzelaar/+archive/opencv2-karmic).  After each, I still get the following from a Python console:

```
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
```

Starting with the "new" Python interface in 2.0, that import is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the python-opencv package in Lucid Lynx and this worked:

`from opencv import cv`
`from opencv import highgui`

Then you should be able to check what functions are available by using dir(cv) and dir(highgui).